# WWW displays different IP than Non-WWW

Tags: networking, dns, ip, www

When i ping the **domain.com** i get **X** IP and when i ping the **www.domain.com** i get **Y** IP address.

I have added the nameservers on the domain host to point to my web server.

The web server IP is **Y**.

When i go to **Y** on the browser i see my site.

The domain www.domain.com works fine on the browser.

What can cause the **domain.com** to not display correctly and instead redirect me to **domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible to set up **www.domain.com** to a different IP address rather than **domain.com** in the DNS configs.

Comment: How do i make domain.com point to the same IP as www.domain.com? This started happening randomly...

Comment: In the admin console you need to change your www. domain name record to DNS 'A' record type and change the IP adress to the main IP address (as the one of domain.com) OR change the type to CNAME and make a redirrect to domain.com

Comment: It seems the domain registrar changed the IP of the domain or something similar and affected the DNS on the web server... anyway the issue is now solved after waiting for some time for the changes to propagate... Thank you all.

Comment: @fxuser you might want to log a complaint, they shouldn't change the IPs without informing you ahead of time.